# Error creating emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am getting this error

> INFO | Android emulator version 33.1.4.0 (build_id 9936625) (CL:N/A)
> INFO | Found systemPath
> C:\SDKs\system-images\android-33\google_apis\x86_64\

I tried changing the emulator version and changing the avd folder from root to home directory. Now this error is showing.